# Fast Bookmarking In Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks

Making  bookmarks in Firefox has become tedious.

Can any one point me to a bookmarking extension that works as follows...

- Decide you want to bookmark a page
- Left click your way to the target bookmark folder
- Right the target bookmark folder to get a "Bookmark this page here" option. (It is this "Bookmark this page here" add on that I am looking for)
- (Edit the book mark title tags etc)
- Click done

Currently you have to:

- Decide you want to bookmark a page
- Click on the bookmarks menu pulldown
- Click on "bookmark this page"
- Click on the "folder" pulldown
- Click on "Bookmarks tool bar"  or "Bookmarks menu"
- Left click your way to the target bookmark folder (in a teeny window that that doesn't move the focus as you expand folders)
- (Edit the book mark title tags etc)
- Click "Done"

That would be four (or five) steps to replace the seven (or eight) steps to make a bookmark in an existing folder.

---

@Chris I assume you are referring me to "Read It Later"

http://www.ideashower.com/ideas/launched/read-it-later/

I'll take a look.

Comment: What's wrong with Control and D?

Comment: Ctrl-D only replaces the "click on the menu pulldown step"

Comment: Why can't you use the star on the rights side of the address bar?

Comment: @SirLancelot - Um - I didn't know about it. When I tried it, it did work, but forces the bookmark into the bookmarks root folder - way too cluttered in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works simpler:

- Navigate to the folder you want to place the bookmark in
- Drag the Page-Icon from address bar to the folder

Comment: An exact functional equivalent of what I was looking for. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here please.

[**5 Excellent Firefox Extensions to Manage your Bookmarks**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-excellent-firefox-extensions-to-manage-your-bookmarks/)

Answer (score 0):

I love [Delicious](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615) it can replace firefox bookmarking (folder by folder) it uses tag then you can manage it easily.

I myself can bookmark my current page in 3 steps. and in other hand can find easily my desire page. you don't limited to 1 folder you label it (taged it) as many as you want then you have 1 page in many folder (tag)